# WP8.1 Popup - Slow to render

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I made a popup control that can accept any view of type `FrameworkElement`. In addition, you can provide a view model, which will be bound to the `DataContext` of the child view being provided. Everything works, but it takes a couple of seconds to render the data. The view model has an `ObservableCollection` that contains about 300 items. So in all honesty, 300 items shouldn't cause any issues.

There is no lag what so ever, If I extract the xaml from the popup to a regular page.

So, is there something inside a `Popup` control that happens when it's `Child` content property is being set, that would cause such a delay? Because this is blowing my mind at the moment.

Thanks in advance!

[Update]
As requested, the XAML that forms the child content of the tool window:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App.Controls.ContactSelector"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="contactSelector"
    DataContext="{Binding ContactSelectorViewModel,Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource BaseGridStyle}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ContactCollection}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="12">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <!--<Image Margin="0,0,10,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                               Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" MaxHeight="35"
                               Visibility="{Binding Thumbnail, Converter={StaticResource ObjectNullToVisibilityConverter}}" />-->
                        <!--<Image Margin="0,5,5,5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" MaxHeight="35"
                               Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Images/Contact.png"
                               Visibility="{Binding Thumbnail, Converter={StaticResource InverseObjectNullToVisibilityConverter}}" />-->

                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FullName}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Style="{StaticResource TextBlockMedium}" />

                        <!--<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding MobileNumbers}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid Margin="10,5">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="0"
                                                       Text="{Binding Number}"
                                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                       Style="{StaticResource TextBlockMedium}">
                                                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                                        <core:InvokeCommandAction
                                                            Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectContact, ElementName=contactSelector}"
                                                            CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </Grid>-->
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <!--<ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           Style="{StaticResource TextBlockMedium}"
                                           Padding="5" Margin="5" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>-->
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

So I have commented out the entire section of the `ItemsControl`, but this did not solve the problem. When the `Popup` opens, it still takes quite a while to show the containing items.

It isn't slow when it's scrolling, it's slow in rendering the initial items.

Comment: Try to use await Task.Delay(50) (maybe after every 20 items) while adding your elements to the ObservableCollection and let your UI breathe.

Comment: How do you render the items, in a `ListView`, or something else. Are you using a virtualized items panel or not? Please edit your answer and include the XAML with the items presenter (your popup child), otherwise we can not know where the problem is.

Comment: @KristianVukusic updated question - thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `ItemsControl` which displays the `MobileNumbers` collection. You should not have an `ItemsControl` as an `ItemTemplate` for another `ItemsControl` (in your case, the `ListView`). You can do that only when you display small amount of items.

Because of this your `MobileNumbers` items are not virtualized and this is where the performance problem comes from, as all the items need to be displayed to render the item template.

You can try creating a flat list of objects, and then use `ItemTemplateSelector` to display different item templates for different types. For example you could have the following `ObservableCollection` as the `ItemsSource`:

```
Header
Contact info
Mobile number1
Mobile number2
Header
Contact info
Mobile number
etc.
```

Comment: many thanks for the reply. I have updated my question. In a nutshell, I removed the entire ItemsControl section. This was just to see if it is causing the issue. Although this did not solve the problem. It's still slow when rendering the items. As soon as the list is populated. The ListView in the Popup scrolls just fine.

Comment: Ok, you have included the `SemanticZoom` part in your latest edit. This is the problem, try to remove the semantic zoom and any parent `ScrollViewer` and see if it fixes the issue. Just display a ListView in your popup, you can include the `ItemsControl` if it only has a few items.

Comment: Ok, so I have removed virtually everything except the ListView (Please see updated question) - and still it's slow to load initially. The view model has already been initialized and the observablecollection already has it's data, so in my opinion the view should just bind and display the data?! o.O